# GoLand (JetbBrains) ask for prompt on run does not work

Tags: go, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, goland

I am trying to configure my build/run in GoLand to prompt for arguments when running the build.

Going into "edit configurations" and setting "Program arguments" and setting it to "$Prompts$" seems like it should work.

But, I am getting

```
Error running 'go build main.go': The DialogWrapper can only be used in event dispatch thread. Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 172,4,Idea Thread Group]
```

When I try to run it.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best place to ask this type of question as we don't have access to all the data required for investigating the bug or suggesting a fix for it.

I suggest that you go via the official support channels: 
- the issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go (read the issue template and do as instructed in it)
- the ZenDesk support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731